# Normal redirect or preload

Tags: javascript, jquery

So on the net I've come across a several ways to preload / redirect a webpage.

Now's the question is this the proper way to handle a redirect with preload (Load the next page async while still showing the current page)

```
$.get("page.php", function (data) {
    document.open();
    document.write(data);
    document.close();
    window.history.pushState("Title", "Title", "/page.php");
    $.cache = {};
}, "html");
```

Or should I better stay with a regular redirect?

```
window.location = "page.php";
```

The next page contains a fullscreen video and a soundtrack (audio)

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Ajax: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)        to load next page async!

Comment: helpful link: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to load next page asynchronous.
Here is an example of a simple Ajax request using the [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_(HTTP)) method, written in [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

> AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML, and for the XMLHttpRequest object to behave as AJAX, the async parameter of the open() method has to be set to true: `xhr.open('get', 'send-ajax-data.php', true);`

get-ajax-data.js:

```
// This is the client-side script.

// Initialize the Ajax request.
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'send-ajax-data.php', true); // `true` makes the request asynchronous

// Track the state changes of the request.
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === OK) {
            alert(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'
        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
        }
    }
};

// Send the request to send-ajax-data.php
xhr.send(null);
```

And at the end you can use below codes to reload or redirect page data:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

Comment: Here's some additional browser compatibility info in case OP is interested http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2